# spark scala : Convert Array of Struct column to String column

Tags: arrays, json, scala, apache-spark

I have a column, which is of type array < Struct > deduced from json file. 
I want to convert the array < Struct > into string, so that i can keep this array column as-is in hive and export it to RDBMS as a single column.

temp.json

```
{"properties":{"items":[{"invoicid":{"value":"923659"},"job_id":
{"value":"296160"},"sku_id":
{"value":"312002"}}],"user_id":"6666","zip_code":"666"}}
```

Processing :

```
scala> val temp = spark.read.json("s3://check/1/temp1.json")
temp: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [properties: struct<items:
array<struct<invoicid:struct<value:string>,job_id:struct<value:string>,sku_id:struct<value:string>>>, user_id: string ... 1 more field>]

    scala> temp.printSchema
    root
     |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- items: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |-- invoicid: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- job_id: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- sku_id: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- zip_code: string (nullable = true)


scala> temp.select("properties").show
+--------------------+
|          properties|
+--------------------+
|[WrappedArray([[9...|
+--------------------+


scala> temp.select("properties.items").show
+--------------------+
|               items|
+--------------------+
|[[[923659],[29616...|
+--------------------+


scala> temp.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable")

scala> spark.sql("select properties.items  from tempTable").show
+--------------------+
|               items|
+--------------------+
|[[[923659],[29616...|
+--------------------+
```

How can i get the result like:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               items                                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[{"invoicid":{"value":"923659"},"job_id":{"value":"296160"},"sku_id":{"value":"312002"}}] |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

to get the array element value without any change.

Comment: [{"invoicid":{"value":"923659"},"job_id":{"value":"296160"},"sku_id":{"value":"312002"}}]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@sort_array(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) is the function you're looking for

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_json:

val df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq("""
  {"properties":{"items":[{"invoicid":{"value":"923659"},"job_id":
  {"value":"296160"},"sku_id":
  {"value":"312002"}}],"user_id":"6666","zip_code":"666"}}""")))


df
  .select(get_json_object(to_json($"properties"), "$.items").alias("items"))
  .show(false)
```

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|items                                                                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"invoicid":{"value":"923659"},"job_id":{"value":"296160"},"sku_id":{"value":"312002"}}]|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How would you extract all the columns attached to the root struct?  For eg, if "properties" did not exist, I was hoping select(get_json_object(to_json(($".*")),"$.value")) would work. But it doesnt.

Comment: `to_json(struct(df.columns map col: _*))`